# Javascript to modify table cell colour on mouseover - Syntax error 800A03EA for javascript

Tags: javascript

Theres this error pop up when I tried to open it with the default microsoft window based script host, but my javascript works fine. When I open in webpages.

I tried to look into it but couldn't find any syntax error.

```
      td.addEventListener("mouseover", modifyColor, false); 
      td.addEventListener("click", clickWhite, false);

const modifyColor = event =>
{
  const color = document.querySelector(".color");
  event.target.style.background = color.value;
}

const clickWhite = event =>
{
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Based on the error message, it pointed to this section of the code.

Comment: is color.value is object that you are accessing it

Comment: I have a HTML selector option that inputs the color value for the javascript.